# Format cell to make calculation with it

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, addition, worksheet-function

My cell A1 contains `EUR 1.00` and A2 `EUR 2.00`. This is in A3:

```
=A1+A2
```

I'm supposed to get `EUR 3.00` or `3,00` but I got error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to use in cell formulas is to only have numbers in the cells that your adding.  i.e. get rid of 'EUR' from A1 and A2 and it will work.  Otherwise excel is trying to add strings instead of numbers.

---

You can also use the 'right()' function to strip out the 'EUR' from each string like this:

```
=RIGHT(A1,4)+RIGHT(A2,4)
```

---

If the input is "EUR 1.5" and "EUR 0.5" and you need "EUR 2,0" as the output try this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE("EUR " & (RIGHT(A1,4)+RIGHT(A2,4)),".",",")
```

---

If your set up as comma deliminated decimal values you'll have to substitute first rather than last.  Try this:

```
="EUR " & (RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",","),4)+RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",","),4))
```

Comment: This leave 1.00 and 2.00 which looks good but my Excel accept only number fromat like 1,00 or 2,00. Any idea?

Comment: Please clarify, do you need both the input and output to use commas as the decimal delimiter?

Comment: this function `SUBSTITUTE` doesn't work for me, did you test it?

Comment: my input is "EUR 2.00" and I would like to get "2,00" as output

Comment: Yes, I tested the substitute.  Try this: =SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",",")

Comment: Yes. My parameter separator is `;` and now it's working perfect. Thank you guys !

Answer (score 3):

Excel is essentially about calculation, hence numbers. Mixing these with text is possible but as mentioned by @Portland Runner, best avoided where convenient. One of the standard options I have under Home > Number – Currency (an icon) is `€ Euro (€ 123)` and if I select a cell containing `1` and format the cell by clicking that choice I see `€     1.00`.

Alternatively, choosing the custom format `"EUR  "#.00##` would display `2` as `EUR 2.00`.
In both formats the addition would result in `3` - formatted as you select.

So I’d recommend doing a search for `EUR` and replace with nothing, then apply formatting to suit. Depending upon your locale (which seems to use `,` as the decimal indicator) you may be advised to replace any `.` in your currency cells first.

Comment: I agree that this is a better all around approach to setting up your spread sheet.  Little bit more involved then what the question was targeting but a better solution in the end.

Comment: You are right but deleting `EUR` everytime I import my data and changing `.` to `,` would be time waster. I would rather have function which can read data as imported

Comment: How to change custom format to display `EUR 2.00` as `2,00` ?

Comment: my `EUR 2.00` is a text

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38305/discussion-between-maniootek-and-pnuts)